# Injecting data from custom component library to its services

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, web-component, angular-library

I'm working on a custom Angular component library that will need to be configured with some parameters when added to other Angular projects. This library needs to be configured with some parameters when it will be added to other Angular projects.

I looked at ways to inject data in Angular services, here's an overview of what has been done:

app.component.html (From other Angular project where we will add this custom library)

```js
<my-component paramA="abc" paramB="def"></my-component>
```

my-component.component.ts

```js
@Component({
...
  providers: [
    { provide: 'paramA', useValue: this.paramA },
    { provide: 'paramB', useValue: this.paramB },
  ]
}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() paramA: string;
    @Input() paramB: string;

constructor(private serviceA: AService, private serviceB: BService);
...
}
```

a.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AService {
    constructor(
        @Inject('paramA') public paramA: string
    ) {
         this.paramA = paramA;
    }
}
```

This throws an error as the component decorator can't access class properties.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I get your problem right, but if you need to configure your library/module, do it when you import it into application. Use static [forRoot](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method) or forChild methods. I think [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/public_api.ts) is a good example of this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I can configure the library when imported since some of the parameters are part of the app's config, while others require a user action (let's say, creating an account)

Comment: For static configuration you can use forRoot/forChild, remember you can pass anything in those methods to increase flexibility, for example functions or objects/services. 
In the case of dynamic data consider creating service exposing data manipulation methods that can be used to address your specific case.

Unfortunately, I know too little about your approach to suggest something more specific.